# get value from third table in trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

How to get the value of Other table for insert the data into the table
This is my code i want to get the StoreId and LangnageId from the other Table

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[NewsTrigger]'))
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[NewsTrigger]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewsTrigger]
       ON [dbo].[News]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;


   DECLARE @EntityId INT
   DECLARE @EntityName varchar
   DECLARE @IsPublish bit
   DECLARE @LanguageId int
   DECLARE @StoreId int
   DECLARE @InTime Datetime   

   SELECT @EntityId = DELETED.Id FROM DELETED    
   Delete from MyCustomtbl where EntityName='News' and EntityId  = @EntityId

   SELECT @EntityId=(Id) FROM INSERTED
   SELECT @IsPublish=(Published) FROM INSERTED
   SELECT @LanguageId=(LanguageId) FROM INSERTED

   INSERT INTO MyCustomtbl(EntityId,EntityName,IsPublish,Status,LanguageId,StoreId,InTime)
                                Values(@EntityId,'News',@IsPublish,1,@LanguageId,@StoreId,GetDate())
```

END
 I want to storeId From Store Table and LangaugeId from the language table in the trigger

Comment: Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It looks SQL-Server, but who knows....

Answer (score 0):

You can SET the Store and language ID in your Trigger aft having declared the variables. For example:

```
DECLARE @StoreId INT

SET @StoreId = (Select StoreId from StoreIds as a where a.storeid = inserted.storeid);
```

That should do the Job, if I have Interpreted your question correctly.